# How to position a sprite at a particular point of the canvas callout?

Tags: three.js, html5-canvas, sprite

I have a html canvas callout similar to picture below:

[image]

I added this canvas to a `THREE.Texture` and created a `THREE.Sprite` from that texture.

Now I want to position the sprite at a particular `(x0, y0, z0)` but I would like the callout's pointer end ( the point where the pointer ends - the corner ) to be the sprite's position.

If I say

```
sprite.position.x = x0
sprite.position.y = y0
sprite.position.z = z0
```

It seems that the sprite is positioned such that the bottom-right corner of the rectangle is placed at `(x0, y0, z0)`, I would like the pointer end to be placed at `(x0, y0, z0)` I tried translating the `(x0, y0, z0)` by calculating offsets, but the sprite is not showing up where I intended it to.

How can I place the sprite like that? Any advice please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply modify sprite [center](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Sprite.center) (sprite's anchor point), e.g. :

```
sprite.center.set(0, 0);
```

Comment: I thought about it, it seems that `center` is a new property in three.js' sprite? Or at least in the version that I am working on, sprite.center is not defined.

Comment: I upgraded the threejs and played with center and it worked. Thanks.